# SQL How do I get highscore and number of rows as attempts

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables
PLAYERS and GAMES
When a new game starts, I add a new GAME record with a playerID to the database, so the data might look like this:

GAMES
**Id  Score PlayerId**
1   200    10
2   100    10
3   500    10
4   100    11
5   200    11

Question: How do I query this if I want to get the highest score and sum of rows as the number of attempts, to get this result:

**Id  Highscore PlayerId Attempts**
1   500       10    3
2   200       11    2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT PlayerId
     , MAX(score) Highscore
     , COUNT(*) Attempts
FROM GAMES
GROUP BY PlayerId
```